# Captcha algorithm

Tags: captcha, verification, interaction-design

I've notised that Stack Overflow only presents me with a captcha occasionally. Does anyone know if it has a good algorithm for sensing if I might be a robot or, instead if it's just random.

Reducing reliance on captchas is obviously a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stackoverflow.com uses [reCAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.net/). And, I too have noticed that when you try to edit the same question many times in a gap of a few seconds, it displays the captcha verification page.

Most of the CAPTCHA generation algorithms are strong enough. [This](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-Easy-Could-A-CAPTCHA-Be-Broken-80151.shtml) article describes the factors influencing a CAPTCHA's strength.

Answer (score 2):

My impression is that SO monitors user's activity and presents captcha in case of suspicious beaviour, for example in case of frecuent posts or comments.

Answer (score 1):

It appears when you post (or edit) the same entry or an entry in the same question many times. It had appeared to me when I edit twice in less than a minute

Answer (score 1):

I've never been confronted with a Captcha at SO because I used a google account and have not given it any reason to suspect me of being a bot I guess. If you don't create local logins you save yourself the trouble of Captcha and storing passwords.

*EDIT* I have now seen several captchas on the site, don't really have any idea what triggers them.

Comment: I use also a Google account and CAPTCHA appears some times when I edit repeatedly any item, that's not a factor